# Local kafka cluster "__consumer_offsets" leader not available

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-cluster

I've setup a local kafka cluster following [this blog](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/configure-apache-kafka/), but I can't make it work. When I use the CLI with the following commands I can't consume the messages because they don't appear.

`./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --from-beginning --topic topic-1`

`./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic topic-1`

After some troubleshooting I've found that with `kafkacat` all `__consumer_offsets` are missing their leader. And I think that may be my problem.

```
3 brokers:
  broker 2 at kevin-UX390UAK:9094
  broker 3 at kevin-UX390UAK:9095
  broker 1 at kevin-UX390UAK:9093
 3 topics:
  topic "test-topic" with 1 partitions:
   ...
  topic "topic-1" with 3 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 2, replicas: 2,1,3, isrs: 1,2,3
    partition 2, leader 1, replicas: 1,3,2, isrs: 1,2,3
    partition 1, leader 3, replicas: 3,2,1, isrs: 1,2,3
  topic "__consumer_offsets" with 50 partitions:
partition 0, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 10, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 20, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 40, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 30, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 9, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 11, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 31, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 39, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 13, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 18, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 22, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 8, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 32, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 43, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 29, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 34, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 1, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 6, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 41, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 27, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 48, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 5, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 15, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 35, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 25, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 46, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 26, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 36, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 44, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 16, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 37, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 17, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 45, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 3, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 24, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 38, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 33, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 23, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 28, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 2, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 12, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 19, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 14, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 4, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 47, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 49, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 42, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 7, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
    partition 21, leader -1, replicas: 0, isrs: 0, Broker: Leader not available
```

And idea what could cause this ?
Many thanks !

Kev